# I want to show all rows of database as list view.But I am having only one

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to show all rows of database as list view. But I am having only one. How can I get all the rows? Here is my `MainAcitvity.class`. I don't know much about Cursor. I think this might be the cause.

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("PhoneBook.db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PhoneBook(NAME VARCHAR,PHONE_NO VARCHAR,EMAIL VARCHAR);");


    Cursor c =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PhoneBook" ,null);

    totalcontact=c.getCount();

    if (totalcontact==0) {

       final  Dialog d =new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

        d.setCancelable(true);


        Button b =(Button)d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.helpmenu);

                 d.dismiss(); 
            }

        });
       d.show();
    }
    else
    {
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(totalcontact!=0)
        {

         pName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
         pPhone=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PHONE_NO"));
         pEmail=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));

    List<PhoneBook> listPhoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();
    listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e2),
            ""+pName+"", ""+pPhone+"", ""+pEmail+""));
    PhoneBookAdapter adapter = new PhoneBookAdapter(this, listPhoneBook);
    lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
    c.moveToNext();
    totalcontact=totalcontact-1;
          }
    c.close();


    }
    db.close();
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: why dont you use CursorAdapter???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new `List` at each iteration.

Declare it outside the loop :

```
c.moveToFirst();
List<PhoneBook> listPhoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();

while(totalcontact!=0){    
         pName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
         pPhone=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PHONE_NO"));
         pEmail=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));    
         listPhoneBook.add(new PhoneBook(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e2),
            ""+pName+"", ""+pPhone+"", ""+pEmail+""));
         c.moveToNext();
         totalcontact=totalcontact-1;
 }
 c.close();
 PhoneBookAdapter adapter = new PhoneBookAdapter(this, listPhoneBook);
 lvPhone.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: dont iterate over the Cursor, use CursorAdapter instead